# How to install LG NetCast App on WebOS Smart TV

Tags: smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I can install a webOS app on a webOS tv without problem using the ares tools.

LG have told me that webOS devices also support NetCast and Smart TV Alliance apps in compatibility mode, however, I cannot figure out how to install either a NetCast or STA app on a webOS device in compatibility mode.  Has anyone figured it out?

Answer (score 2):

You need to package your app with ares tools that contains a file named **appinfo.json**

The file needs to contain below lines (at least for my case);

```
 "id": "app package name",
"icon": "icon.png",
"title": "App Title",
"vendor": "App Vendor",
"testMode": "devTest",
"trustLevel": "netcast", //this line is important
"resolution": "1280x720",
"uiRevision": 2,
"largeIcon": "largeIcon.png",
"type": "web",
"main": "index.html",
"version": "0.0.1"
```

Then you will use the command `ares-package <folder-path-to-lgApp-contains-above-file>`

Then this will make sure you have an ipk just like the one for webos.